# WPF Data Binding - Data Template is not Getting Values

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding

I have the following DataTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Client:WorkItem}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Name="lblIDText" Margin="2">WI ID:</Label>
        <Label Name="lblID" Margin="2" Grid.Column="1" 
               Target="{Binding Id}"></Label>

        <Label Name="lblTitleText" Grid.Row="1" Margin="2">WI Title:</Label>
        <Label Name="lblTitle" Margin="2" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
               Target="{Binding Title}"></Label>

    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

in my `<Window.Resources>` section.  It is meant to show the Id and Title of a WorkItem object (from namespace `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client`.)

I try to put this in a `TabItem` in a `TabControl` and it only shows the static text.  (The WorkItem ID and title do not show, but the static text in my template does.)

Clearly the template is being fired, but the binding is not working and I can't seem to see why.

Here is my C# that calls it:

```
    private void PickWorkItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int Id = int.Parse(((Button) e.OriginalSource).Tag.ToString());

        _mediator.PickedWorkItem = GetWorkItemInQueryResultListByID(Id);
        tabAddLinks.DataContext = _mediator.PickedWorkItem;
        tabAddLinks.Content = _mediator.PickedWorkItem;

    }
```

I tried it with DataContext in and out and it works the same.  When I debug, the value for _mediator.PickedWorkItem is set correctly (Id and Title are both fine).

Any ideas on how to fix this would be appreciated.

Comment: I am stupid!  That is what I get for copy and pasting code!  Anyway.  Thanks for the great (and quick answers).  As they were all right I upvoted all and gave the answer to the first.

Comment: Indeed you were.  Sorry about the mix up (wrong sorting tab selected).  I have changed the answer to reflect that.  Thanks for catching it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're binding the `Label`'s `Target` property, when you actually want to be binding it's `Content` property:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Id}"/>
```

Also, consider using a `TextBlock` instead of a `Label` if you don't need the extra functionality a `Label` provides:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are binding Label.Target.  Target is the UIElement being labelled.  You need to bind Label.Content, or change it to a TextBlock and bind TextBlock.Text.

(My guess would be that you were trying to bind a non-existent Label.Text property and Intellisense helpfully chose Target for you instead...!)

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty new to WPF, so excuse me if I'm off base, but don't you need to set the `Content` property of the label, not the `Target`?